# Why is Homebrew running MySQL service as root and how to change it?

Tags: homebrew, mysql, root

I used `brew update` `brew upgrade mysql` to bump version from 8.0.23 to 8.0.26 and now MySQL service won't start anymore. I try `brew services start mysql` and after few seconds the service status goes back to stopped. The last line in .err files in `/usr/local/var/mysql` says

```
[ERROR] [MY-010123] [Server] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
```

And when I delete the .err files they come back as owned by root. They were not owned by root before.

My current user is not `root` and I do not use `sudo` to run these commands. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it myself by adding explicitly non-root user to ~/.my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
user=jva
```

Still don't know what caused it.